# хочу написать команду для бота, чтобы он менял имя юзера(в списке имен), если тот пожелает

Tags: node.js

Не могу понять, как зациклить чтение, например, если хочу, чтобы юзер ввел
свое новое имя, а бот спросил, действительно ли юзер хочет так называться(тут
бот читает ответ (да или нет)) и изменял в списке имен имя на желаемое, но не
выходит

```
    var pep = new Map();
    bot.command(['namech','Сменитьимя'], (ctx)=>{
        ctx.reply('Введите ваше имя');
        var name;
        bot.use((ctx) => {
            name = ctx.body;
            ctx.reply(name+'? Да/Нет');
        });
        bot.use((ctx) => {
            var answer = ctx.body;
            if (choi(answer) == true){
                pep.set(ctx.user_id, name);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

В следующий раз указывайте, что речь идёт о телеграфе и больше информации давайте, а так-же не стесняйтесь юзать теги. Иначе ответа будете долго ждать.

В вашем случае вам поможет метод ctx.waitForAnswer(); Пример кода ниже. Адаптируйте его под себя.

```
bot.command(['namech','Сменитьимя'], async (ctx) => {
  try {
    await ctx.reply('Введите ваше имя');
    await ctx.waitForAnswer();
    await ctx.reply("Действительно ли это имя хотите использовать?");
    // дальше ваш код
  } catch (error) {  // Исключение. Этот код будет вызван в случае, если внутри try будет какая-то ошибка
    throw new Error(error);
  }
});
```

P.S. Пользуйтесь гуглом, ибо там вы ответ найдёте гораздо быстрее. https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/issues/522